# Find the digital root? Is the following question correct? I think it has some mistakes in sample output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a non-negative integer in base26, **print out its digital root**.
The digital root is the single digit number obtained by an iterative process
of finding the sum of digits. In the next iteration, the sum of the digits
in the previous iteration is computed, and the process repeated until
a single digit value is obtained.

**The table for digital number of each alphabets which starts with 0**

[image: The table for digital number of each alphabets which starts with 0]

**Input Format**

The first line of input consists of a decimal integer t denoting the number of test cases. Then t test cases follow. The first line of each test case consists of a decimal integer l denoting the number of digits in the base26 integer. Second line of each test case consists of a base26 integer n.

**Output Format**
For each test case, output the digital root.

**Constraints**
1 <= t <= 10000 (decimal)
0 <= l <= 10000 (decimal)

**Sample Input**
3
6
deaths
10
zzzzzzzzzz
1
a
**Sample Output**
b
z
a

**Explanation**

For **deaths**

d + e + a + t + h + s = bz

b + z = ba

b + a = b

**Answer is **b****

For **zzzzzzzzzz**

z + z + z + z + z + z + z + z + z + z = jq

j + q = z

**Answer is z**

For **a**

**Answer is a**

**PS**: According to the question I am assuming for **deaths** -> 3+4+19+7+18 = 51 (fb)
5+1 = 6 i.e g
So the answer must be g but Why in sample outputs the answer was b???

And the same logic goes for zzzzzzzzzz = 250 = 7 = h but how the op will be z????

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    l = int(input())
    n = input()
    testlist = []
    alpha = 'a'
    for i in range(0,26):
        testlist.append(alpha)
        alpha = chr(ord(alpha)+1)
    #print(testlist)
    r = n
    while l>1:
        count = 0
        for i in r:
            count = count + testlist.index(i)
        r = ''
        for i in str(count):
            i = int(i)
            r = r+testlist[i]
        l = len(r)
    
    print(r)
```

Comment: 51 is bz in that system.

Comment: May I know how?

Comment: That's how base26 works. It's not 5 = f and 1 = b put together, it's floor(51/26) = 1 = b and 51%26 = 25 = z.

Answer (score 2):

The given integer is **base26** which can be converted to regular base10(decimal) as follows:

deaths => base26
Steps:

```
    d  e  a  t   h  s
sum(3  4  1  19  7  18)  => 51 

Convert (51)base10  => (?)base26   
    recursively divide the number with 26 and represent them back to base26
    - 51%26 = (1,25)    
    - 1%26 = (0,1) 

    1 = b
    25 = z
    
    Answer = 'bz'
```

Follow above step until you reach the digital root which is 'b' in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Following code takes any string as input and gives the final answer same as the question demands.
**Do give a thumbs up ;)**

```
    ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    N = len(ALPHABET)
    ALPHABET_INDEX = {d: i for i, d in enumerate(ALPHABET, 1)}

    def int_to_column_id(num):
        if num == 0:
            return ""
        else:
            q, r = divmod(num, N)
            return int_to_column_id(q) + ALPHABET[r]

    def column_id_to_int(string):
        result = 0
        for char in string.lower():
                result = result * N + ALPHABET_INDEX[char]
        return result - 1

    string = str(input())
    n = sum([ column_id_to_int(item) for item in string ])
    if string == 'a':
        print('a')
    else:
        while n>25:
            string = str(int_to_column_id(n))
            n = sum([ column_id_to_int(item) for item in string ])
        print(int_to_column_id(n))
```